# Craft CMS 3 Installed but not working

Tags: craft3, install, installation

I have a remote repository with a Craft install and am trying to pull it to a new environment. I run the composer install and Craft & other packages install seemingly correctly, added the .env file and set up the Apache server to point to the /web folder.
When I load up the url I get a visual of the index.php file:

> // Set path constants define('CRAFT_BASE_PATH', dirname(**DIR**));
>   define('CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH', CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'/vendor');
>
> // Load Composer's autoloader require_once
>   CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH.'/autoload.php';
>
> // Load dotenv? if (class_exists('Dotenv\Dotenv') &&
>   file_exists(CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'/.env')) {
>       (new Dotenv\Dotenv(CRAFT_BASE_PATH))->load(); }
>
> // Load and run Craft define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT',
>   getenv('ENVIRONMENT') ?: 'production'); $app = require
>   CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH.'/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php'; $app->run();

No urls seem to be working e.g. /admin or /index.php?p=admin/install and I can even put anything as the url and nothing errors, just shows this file still.

Comment: If the PHP code is getting rendered as HTML then it seems like this is a server issue, is PHP definitely installed? You could create a PHP file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in to check.

Comment: Yep this was it, somehow my new server config had php there and responded with "php -v" but wasn't actually installed, just ran the install for it and works now, thanks!

Comment: @WillBV can you add that as an official answer in case it ends up helping someone in the future?

Answer (score 3):

Your answer didn't end up working for me, but I did get it working.

1. Update (or add) `"vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.0"` to `composer.json`
2. Edit the `craft` (or `index`) file's contents:

```php
// Load dotenv?
// if (class_exists('Dotenv\Dotenv') && file_exists(CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'/.env')) {
//     Dotenv\Dotenv::create(CRAFT_BASE_PATH)->load();
// }
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
if (file_exists(CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'/.env')) {
  $dotenv->load();
}
```

I can then retrieve my environment vars with:

```php
$varOne = $_ENV['VAR_ONE'];
$varTwo = $_SERVER['VAR_TWO'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Now fixed, turns out that with my server config that copied across php was there and appeared to be installed when viewing the version with the command 'php -v' and enabled with 'a2enmod php7.x' but wasn't in fact installed.

Simply re-installed php (with no need to uninstall anything first) then all worked perfectly after that.